# React State update: updating the state in timer do not update the values correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render each element in the `roles` array. This code works in the timer (`setInterval`) is as follows:

1. Assigns the duplicate value of the state in `let prevRole` variable and its corresponding index in the `let prevRoleIndex` variable.
2. Renders the string of random characters 10 times iteratively with 50ms delay.
3. Now the next element in the `roles` array is assigned to `let newRole` variable, by adding +1 to `previousRoleIndex`  and then  updating the state with newRole variable.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const roles = ['Web Developer & UX Designer', 'Software Developer / Engineer', 'Blockchain Developer', 'Data Anaylist/ Scientist']

export default function App() {
 
    const [role, setRole] = useState(roles[0])
    const sleep = (value) =>{
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, value));
    }
    const getRandomString = () =>{
        return (Math.random()).toString(36).substring(2);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(async() => {
            console.log("Timer has started")

            let prevRole = role;
            let prevRoleIndex = roles.findIndex((ele)=>ele===prevRole)
            
            console.log("Previous Role State: "+ prevRole)
            
            for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
                setRole(getRandomString())
                await sleep(50)
            }

            prevRoleIndex = prevRoleIndex+1 >= roles.length? -1: prevRoleIndex
            let newRole = roles[prevRoleIndex+1]
            
            console.log("New Role State: "+ newRole)
            
            setRole(newRole)
          }, 3000);
          return () => clearInterval(timer);
        }, []);
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>{role}</h1>
          </div>
    )
}
```

The code works fine during first timer iteration and after second iteration the state does not update.

Comment: Your assumption that `prevRole` refers to the *previous value* of some previous render is wrong here. You have one closure (the callback to `setInterval`) that never changes because of the empty dependencies to `useEffect`. As such `role` will always and forever refer to that *first render*. In a sense, it's basically the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately).

Comment: I have used `react-usestateref` package and assigned `ref.current` for `prevRole` it gave me the output what I am expecting.